# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my *Spring Boot* application, I have two models. Actually trying to implement `ManyToMany` relationship.

A:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Set<B> b=new HashSet<>();
    public A() {

    }
}
```

B:

```
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Set<A> a=new HashSet<>();
    public B() {

    }

}
```

When I try to compile this this gives me error, saying :
*Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: a, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(b)]*

Full log : [here](https://pastebin.com/0EDxnyNa)

Comment: Did you define your relations `ManyToOne`  or other? Also id does not make sense to `B` having `Set` of `A` and vice versa. If you mean `ManyToMany` relationship, it does not work like that

Comment: I getting error only for two days, can you post an answer. Yes I'm trying to create a `ManyToMany` relationship @HoussemBadri

Comment: if you want to implement `@ManyToMany` relationship, where have you implement it?

Comment: If you want to add `ManyToMany` relation you need to add an intermediate table, that relationship would be change to `OneToMnay` and `ManyToOne`. Have a look at this link: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: @Patrick I'm little confused with this `ManyToMany` relation, can you help me with this?

Comment: @HoussemBadri I tried `@JoinTable(name ="...",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "..."), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "..."))` ... And this works, and creates table. **But the problem is I don't know how to retrieve data from this table?** And I'm not sure if they are updating or not ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)//don't use fetch here
    private List<B> b=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

B:

```
@Entity
public class B {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)//don't use fetch here
    private List<A> a=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Don't use fetch on **OneToMany** or **ManyToMany** meaning ***ToMany**